# Diff 2 sets of rows in Google Sheets

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, filter, count, countif

Is there a simple way of diff'ing 2 sets of rows of data in Google Sheets?
e.g.
Sheet 1 - contains 10 rows

```
One
Two 
Three
Four 
Five
Six 
Seven
Eight
Nine
Ten
```

Sheet 2 contains 13 rows

```
One
Three
Five
Six 
Seven
Eight
Nine
Ten
Eleven
Twelve
Thirteen
Fourteen
Fifteen
```

Ideally i'd like to be able to run some formula to diff the two data sets to identify the additions and deletions in the second data set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=FILTER(A:A, COUNTIF(B:B, A:A))
```

[image]

and:

```
=FILTER(A:A, NOT(COUNTIF(B:B, A:A)))
```

[image]

or interchange A:A & B:B

Comment: While this is nice (thanks!) - it doesn't account for the new rows added in B:B
Col C is showing what is common to A and B only.

Comment: @ColmTroy did you interchange A:A & B:B ?

Comment: i did not! aha! yes:)
this did the trick:
deletions
=FILTER(A:A, NOT(COUNTIF(B:B, A:A)))
additions
=FILTER(B:B, NOT(COUNTIF(A:A, B:B)))

Comment: thanks so much @player0 - i'll mark your answer as accepted now!

Answer (score 0):

One option is to match values in both sets and then check if all have been found or not.

```
=AND(ARRAYFORMULA(IF(Sheet5!A1:A="",,IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(Sheet5!A1:A,Sheet6!A:A,1,false)),FALSE,TRUE))))
```

This formula will check if every value in Sheet5 is present in Sheet6.

If all of them have been found, then the result will be TRUE.

Comment: Thanks David - this is nice a sanity check/checksum, but it doesn't give me the diff (i.e. specific rows added/removed).